# Hall Seat Layout Design Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

How to make hall seat that contains more than 1200 seats in android?
For references design please look at below image. Please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a horizontal `NestedScrollView`, and inside it create a `LinearLayout` in the root of it, and inside that, draw your seating design by using `View`s as each seat. When that's done, surround your horizontal `NestedScrollView` by another vertical `NestedScrollView`.